# IE 11 only works without Add-ons

Tags: internet-explorer

There are two programs related to the Internet Explorer on my computer:

1) Internet Explorer
2) Internet Explorer (No Add-ons)

The first IE program does not response to any url I entered. Also, most menu items are grey, which are not clickable. I did not install any add-on manually. Since the "Manage add-ons" menu item is grey, I have no way to check which add-on is causing this issue.

The second IE program works correctly.

I have posted this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419041/ie-11-only-works-without-add-ons, but someone recommended me to move my question here.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to manage your add-ons when you start IE with all ad-ons disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this (at least until next time) by resetting your IE.

1. Make sure no IE processes are open with Task Manager.
2. Run inetcpl.cpl in the start menu, or go to the control panel and open "internet options".
3. Choose "Advanced" tab, and click "Reset" and then "Reset" again.
4. If you are part of a domain network you should run afterwords "GPupdate /Force" in the start menu.

If you want to further debug this, than instead of resetting you should go to addons management (inetcpl.cpl > programs > Manage addons) and start eliminating them one by one.

I've come across this in my organization several times but failed to find a normal solution.
Even when I've disabled all addons (including the "system" addons) manually it still didn't work.